# Would/could a severed Golem arm serve as an effective weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, improvised-weaponry

Subject is D&D.

I've been thinking of ripping a golem's arm off and using it as a melee weapon.
(mainly for non serious fun).

Some of my friends have voiced their opinion that it would not be as strong as stuff that is meant to be a weapon.

In my opinion, wouldn't a strong enough character be able to handle it to the point that it would serve as a useful club or mace?
Getting hit in the face with the shoulder end of a golems arm would hurt alot.

PS. Im thinking of a human sized or slightly larger golem.  With a golem the size of a building I would understand it not being as plausible.

Secondary question:
With the size and weight, a Golem's arm could be considered a mace or club. But if the wrist and elbow still functioned, thus making the arm semi-flexible, could it also count as a flail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Improvised weapons

The simplest way to rule this is to consider the golem's arm as an improvised weapon. (PHB p. 147; table on p. 149 lists all of the weapons).  If your DM goes along with making it a club, it does the same damage (1d4) as an improvised weapon (1d4).

If your DM is as amused as your are, sure, for someone with a martial weapons proficiency you can make it act as a flail with the joints in place.  That's  beyond the scope of the rules and in the area of a DM ruling and Rules as Fun.
(Note: per table on p. 149 flail is a martial weapon. A mace or  club is a simple weapon).
Work with your DM.